# Asp.net core web API: Change default encoding. How can i accept vietnamese characters as actions parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi i have this controller's action:

```
[HttpGet("vn/{word}", Name = "GetTranslationForVnWord")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTranslationForVnWord(string word)
{
    return Ok(word);
}
```

I got this exception when sending a get request with a vietnamese characters (utf-16) in it:

Request : [http://localhost:53976/api/gervntranslations/vn/kéo](http://localhost:53976/api/gervntranslations/vn/k%C3%A9o)

Exception:

> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [E9]
>   at index 26 from specified code page to Unicode.    at
>   System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown,
>   Int32 index)    at
>   System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[]
>   bytesUnknown, Int32 index)    at
>   System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte*
>   pBytes)    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetCharCount(Byte* bytes, Int32
>   count, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)    at
>   System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength,
>   Encoding encoding)    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[]
>   bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestUriBuilder.DecodeAndUnescapePath(Byte[]
>   rawUrlBytes)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.GetOriginalPath() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer.HandleRequest(IISHttpContext
>   context)

How can i configure asp.net core in order to avoid this problem?